# Seeding database with tasks that belong to a user

Tags: php, laravel

My laravel version is `Laravel Framework 5.5.22`.

I have the following Schema for tasks:

```
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Within my `TaskTableSeeder` class I want to assign every `user` some `tasks`.
See below what I tried:

```
class TaskTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
        $limit = 25;

        $userIds = DB::table('users')->get('id');      

        for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
            DB::table('tasks')->insert([
                'name' => $faker->sentence(),
                'user_id' => $faker->randomElement($userIds),
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Seeding: UserTableSeeder
Seeding: TaskTableSeeder

In Grammar.php line 124:

  Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, call
  ed in C:\Users\marcus\Desktop\Coding Projects\demo_laravel_todo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\
  Grammars\Grammar.php on line 131
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're passing string to `randomElement()`. You need to pass an array to `randomElement()`, so use `pluck()` and `toArray()`:

```
$userIds = DB::table('users')->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass **array of arrays** instead passing only **single array** in [insert](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#inserts) function .Change you code from

```
   for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
        DB::table('tasks')->insert([
            'name' => $faker->sentence(),
            'user_id' => $faker->randomElement($userIds),
        ]);
    }
```

To

```
   $insertData = array();
   for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
        $insertData[] = [
            'name' => $faker->sentence(),
            'user_id' => $faker->randomElement($userIds),
        ];
    }
    DB::table('tasks')->insert($insertData);
```

Check below example in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#inserts)

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
]);
```